# GPO: User logon script not running

Tags: group-policy, scripting

I have a GPO that is linked to an OU containing computers. Loopback processing is activated an set to merge. Within the user part of the GPO i have a powershell script defined that basically checks if its running inside a remode desktop session (if ($env:SESSIONNAME -ne 'Console')) and then tries to set an environment variable based on a modification of $env:CLIENTNAME.

However the script seems not to work as at the time of execution there is no $env:CLIENTNAME. How can i fix this?

I have already tried to enable and disable "Run logon scripts synchronously". If i enable it - no luck, which seems logical. When set to "Not configured" the above mentioned happens. Thanks for your input.

[EDIT]

When I invoke the script via "User Configuration => Policies => Administrative Templates => System => Logon => Run these programs at user logon" it seems to work. However not for every user and with a random latency.

Is there another way I can use powershell to query for %CLIENTNAME%? Like asking the remote desktop servies for logged in users... can you see where i am pointing at?

Answer (score 2):

This link here helped me to solve my problem:

http://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/how-to-get-clientname-within-logon-script-on-server-2008-r2-xenapp-6/

Now I am parsing the output of qwinsta and read the clientname from the registry which is earlier available then the var %CLIENTNAME%

```
Function Get-ClientName 
{
    $session = qwinsta $env:USERNAME
    $sessionId = $session[1].subString(39,9).Trim()

    return (Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Volatile Environment\${sessionId}\" -Name CLIENTNAME).CLIENTNAME
}
```

Then I am able to load my script from "User Configuration => Policies => Windows Settings => Scripts => Logon ..."

Comment: Thanks this function works like a charm! You're saving me a headache!!!